# How to emmit event through python socket io? It is working on my local machine but i am having hard time figuring out to run in server

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, websocket, socket.io, python-socketio

I am not being able to emmit event through python socket io in server. Can somebody help me i am able to do it in my local machine. I think it is problem with namespace but i am not being able to figure it out.

- my server.py *

```
@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    game_id = environ.get("HTTP_GAME_ID", "")
    sio.enter_room(sid, game_id)

def my_function(data, game_id):
    sio.emit("my_event", {"data": data}, to=game_id, namespace='/join-game')
```

- nginx.config *

```
location /join-game {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    proxy_pass http://<my-ip>;
}
```

I connect from url:

```
http://<my-ip>/join-game
```

When i am listening to my_event it does not emit event.

Comment: The namespace has nothing to do with the URL. The location of your server is `/socket.io`.

Comment: Thanks @Miguel for the help.